# what is the drawbacks for using Apache Axis as a wrapper to capture the request/response?

Tags: java, web-services, axis

what is the drawbacks for using Apache Axis as a wrapper to capture the request/response??
What problems I could face by using the axis handler??

Answer (score 0):

Axis is designed for full-blown SOA work. If you need something light-weight you're better off just using the Servlet API because servlets provide a decent enough abstraction layer on top of HTTP to get you access to the meat of the request and response.

If you want something higher level that can do things like map incoming JSON payloads into POJOs, I'd recommend Apache CXF over Axis. CXF is a very light weight and easy framework that is good for REST and SOAP.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, so do u mean that using Axis willbe more complicated. What kind of problems i could face???